# Using functions with two seperate files

Tags: c

Files: A(main), B

I have learned that B's function can't be use in A without 
funcntion definitions.

But my code ran normally with A, B files without function definitions

This is my code:

B.c

```
void a()
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

A.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    a();
}
```

What is it? I'm confused.

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

addendum...
sorry for my bad question.
my code works well with error.
but i couldn't see error.

but i have more question for difference between 
'void a();'
'extern void a();'

Comment: How do you build your program? Do you list both source files when you build? Do you have a forward declaration of the function `a` in the (weirdly named) source file `A.c`? What errors do you get? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What OS are you using? How are you compiling? Which compiler? (Presuming gcc) Are you compiling using `-Wall -Werror`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is knowledge easy to find in any C book or tutorial. It is not the programming problem

Comment: Your B.c does supply the definition of `a()` - which is necessary, since a program can't be built if a function it calls is not implemented.     A.c does not *declare* `a()` before calling it.  In older versions of C, no declaration was required, since the compiler would make assumptions, and the functions were then described as "implicilty declared".   In recent versions of C that was removed.   Also, in standard C (and even in C before the first C standard) `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: @P__J__ Easy to find what knowledge?  The OP knows he needs external declarations.  The question is, if he needs declarations, how did he get away without them?  That's not so obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once upon a time, C did not require prior declaration of all functions.  Many compilers still let you get away with this.

In file `A.c`, when you called

```
a();
```

where `a` was a function the compiler has never seen before, the compiler assumed that the declaration

```
extern int a();
```

was in scope.  That is, the compiler assumed that `a` was a function taking unspecified arguments and returning `int`.

Or, that *used* to be the rule.  That rule is no longer in C, so yes, you are supposed to explicitly declare *all* your functions before you call them.  Most of today's compilers will warn you when they apply the old rule, and many aren't willing to apply the rule at all, or at least, not unless you use a non-default option flag requesting them to.  But it sounds like your compiler is still willing to apply the rule without warning or error.  That's great if you're compiling a bunch of very old code, but it's not so great if you're trying to learn modern C.

Now, in this case you have the additional problem that the *actual* definition of function `a` in file `B.c` defines it as returning `void`, not `int`, so theoretically that's wrong, too.  But, in practice, the error of misdeclaring (or mis-calling) `void`- versus `int`-returning functions is an innocuous one, that doesn't cause any real problems.  (It's still wrong, though, and worth avoiding.)

I think you know this, but a correct setup would either be to have file `A.c` look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void a(void);
int main()
{
    a();
}
```

or else to create the file `B.h` containing

```
extern void a(void);
```

and then to have file `A.c` look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "B.h"
int main()
{
    a();
}
```

(Note that I have also changed `void main()` to `int main()`, for correctness.  If you're using an old compiler, as it sounds like you are, you may also have to add the line `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.)

---

Addendum.  You had also asked about that `extern` keyword.  It has to do with the distinction between *declarations* and *definitions*.  But this distinction plays out slightly differently for functions, versus global variables.

Declarations explain what type something has.  Definitions explain what type something has, *and* they additionally allocate memory for the something, and supply its initial value.

These are declarations:

```
extern int i;
int f(int);
extern int f2(int, double);
```

These are definitions:

```
int i;
int i2 = 2;
int f(int x) { return 2 * x; }
int f2(int n, double x) { return n * x; }
```

The keyword `extern` explicitly says, "This is a declaration, the definition is somewhere else."  For global variables, this makes a big difference.  But for functions, when you say `int f(int);`, the compiler can tell, when it finds a `,` instead of a `{`, that this is a declaration (not a definition), so the keyword `extern` is optional in function declarations.

(Also, functions are always global in C; there are no local functions.)

See also [section 4.2](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx4b.html) and [section 4.3](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx4c.html) of [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/top.html).

Comment: all function declarations are extern by default in C  `extern` is not neede at all

Comment: Minor nitpick: the implicit declaration would be `extern int a();`, not `extern int a(void);` (although the `extern` is redundant),

Comment: thanks!!
but i want know difference between

'void a();'
'extern void a();'

two sentences work nomarlly

Comment: @IanAbbott Doh!  Thanks.  Fixed.  (And I'd say that's more than minor.)

Comment: @organismLee See the addendum I just added about the significance (or non-significance) of the `extern` keyword